# cURL post form and return the result

Tags: php

i'm trying to get result from this site by using cURL. its just return white page not with the download link.what's wrong with my code?

This's my codes

```
<?php
// Define URL where the form resides
$form_url = "http://www.tusfiles.net/83gjiu9h49nw";

// This is the data to POST to the form. The KEY of the array is the name of the field. The value is the value posted.
$data_to_post = array();
$data_to_post['op'] = 'download2';
$data_to_post['id'] = '83gjiu9h49nw';
$data_to_post['rand'] = 'utpaxiqp4ocv6krspq5geslurstt7z3bmvt5eqa';
$data_to_post['referer'] = '';
$data_to_post['method_free'] = '';
$data_to_post['method_premium'] = '';
$data_to_post['submit'] = 'Direct download link';

// Initialize cURL
$curl = curl_init();

// Set the options

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $form_url);

// This sets the number of fields to post
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, sizeof($data_to_post));

// This is the fields to post in the form of an array.
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_to_post);

//execute the post
$result = curl_exec($curl);

//close the connection
curl_close($curl);

?>
```

Thx

Comment: Why do you set `CURLOPT_POST` to the number of fields? It's supposed to be `true` or `false`.

Comment: Check `$result` to see if the request was successful.

Comment: @Barmar i try to change curloprt_post 1 or 0, and echo the $result. it returns number 1 not the download link. what the problem exactly?

Comment: You don't set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to true, why do you expect `$result` to contain the download link?

Comment: @Barmar i already set to true. same result return number 1. my reason is just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to url encode the data in the body of your POST request.
So instead of:

```
$data_to_post['submit'] = 'Direct download link';
```

You'd have:

```
$data_to_post['submit'] = urlencode('Direct download link');
```

Comment: what do you means? may u post the complete code? so i can analyze what's wrong with my code. because, i'm still get empty result.

Comment: You don't need to call `urlencode()`. cURL does this automatically when it serializes the data array for posting.